Recomposing Issue with Image due to ModalBottomSheet state changing
I faced an issue due to using if condition and a variable state in showing ModalBottomSheet.
In the code below, I want to change user profile image with one of two methods:

Camera
Single Photo Picker

then I will send it to function to detect if the image has face or not.
if it has a face then I will send it back to the viewmodel.
the problem is when I click change the image recomposed due to changing of showChooserSheet, so what can I do to overcome the problem?, Note that I have tried hiding the sheet using scope.launch { state.hide() } doesn't work as it freezes the UI and the bottom sheet also still in the screen in the bottom.
Here is my code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun PhotoSelectorView(
    profileImage: String?,
    onChangeProfileImage: (File) -> Unit,
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val file by remember { mutableStateOf(context.createImageFile()) }
    val uri by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                Objects.requireNonNull(context),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file
            )
        )
    }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    var selectedImageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)
    }
    var capturedImageUri by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Uri>(Uri.EMPTY)
    }


    val singlePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
        onResult = { uriImage -> selectedImageUri = uriImage }
    )


    val cameraLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
            onResult = { isPictureTaken ->
                if (isPictureTaken) {
                    capturedImageUri = uri
                }
            }
        )
    val permissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
    ) {
        if (it) {
            cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    var showChooserSheet by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    if (showChooserSheet) {
        UploadPhotoOptionsSheet(
            bottomSheetState = sheetState,
            onDismissRequest = {
                scope.launch {
                    sheetState.hide()
                    showChooserSheet = false
                }
            },
            onTakePhoto = {
                permissionLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                showChooserSheet = false
                selectedImageUri = null
            },
            onChooseFromGallery = {
                singlePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(
                    PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
                )
                showChooserSheet = false
                capturedImageUri = Uri.EMPTY
            },
            isDark = isSystemInDarkTheme()
        )
    }

    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        model = ImageRequest
            .Builder(context = context)
            .data(
                if (capturedImageUri != Uri.EMPTY) capturedImageUri
                else if (selectedImageUri != null) selectedImageUri
                else profileImage?.convertToBitmap()
            )
            .crossfade(true)
            .build(),
        contentDescription = null,
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        loading = {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        },
        error = {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.user_img),
                contentDescription = null
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(150.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
    )


    MyTextButton(
        text = R.string.change,
        onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                showChooserSheet = true
                sheetState.show()
            }
        },
        isUnderlined = false
    )

    LaunchedEffect(selectedImageUri, capturedImageUri) {
        if (selectedImageUri != null) {
            detectFace(context, selectedImageUri!!, { hasFace ->
                if (hasFace) {
                    val tempFile = selectedImageUri!!.createFileFromUri(context)
                    onChangeProfileImage(tempFile)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.face_not_detected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    selectedImageUri = null
                }
            }, {
                Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                selectedImageUri = null
            })
        }

        if (capturedImageUri != Uri.EMPTY) {
            detectFace(context, capturedImageUri, { hasFace ->
                if (hasFace) {
                    val tempFile = capturedImageUri.createFileFromUri(context)
                    onChangeProfileImage(tempFile)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.face_not_detected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    capturedImageUri = Uri.EMPTY
                }
            }, {
                Toast.makeText(context, it.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                capturedImageUri = Uri.EMPTY
            })
        }
    }
}


